# How to remove previoulsly mounted drive icon from Ubuntu Dash home?

Tags: icons, drive, gnome-dash

Whenever I insert a new drive a drive icon is generated in dash home and doesn't get remove when eject the drive. Like a lot of drive icons have been generated. I believe that I have pushed some buttons in settings, but cannot get a hold of it.

Whenever I try to unmount it by right-click it takes me to the main window page.

[image]